# Redirect to link in QR code using nodeMCU

Tags: http, arduino, arduino-esp32

I have a code which decodes the scanned QR code and gives the redirection link.I just want to open the link in browser window of my lap im running the Arduino ide from . Is there any way possible to it.

Im doing a QR code based sales webpage on scanning the qr the order page of the specific product must be opened ..

Comment: I don't want to obtain the response I want the page to opened in browser

Comment: The short answer is "possible" but we have no idea what you are running on your ESP32? What have you tried? A QR code is just a URL, and you click it, the server serves a new page or the data requested depend on the request from the mobile. Are you running a server on NodeMCU? Do you have a route setup for listening to the request from the URL? Please update your question (not reply in comment) to add more info otherwise your question is risk to be closed due to lack of info.